# Why doesn't display own flieds in FE by sr_feuser_register?

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.7.x, sr-feuser-registration

I add some fields into fe_users with an own extension. In Typo3 8.7. When I logged in the Backend from Typo3 and in another Tab I open the Webpage I see my added fields in the registration form from sr_feuser_register, but when I logoff Typo3 backend, the labels are empty in the registration form. The value fields are displayed, but with no content, and new content don't saved.

What do I wrong?

The Only thing I found, is:

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['fe_users']['feInterface']['fe_admin_fieldList'] .= 'field1,field2...';
```

But this, don't help.

Thanks for any help

Update:

I found a Bug: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/84587

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the code from `ext_tables.php` to `YourExtension/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/fe_users.php` help. Problem is solved.